# this works in developer mode with breakpoint ....but doesnt work without it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox which is passed to the api....the text entered is stored...

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Type something">
```

The below code works in developer mode of chrome with breakpoints but doesnt work without it...

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var name = $('#name').val() ;
  var url =  "https://www.mariyano.com/app-server/test/?action=add_list&name="+name;
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
  });
```

Comment: What's wrong? And what should be the result?

Comment: Did you close the brackets correctly (asking just in case).

Comment: @nhahtdh ya i closed the brackers

Comment: What is `#submit`? Is it an `input type="submit"` or `button type="submit"`, and is it placed within a `form`? If so, the form might be submitting (and thus navigating to the form's `action` before the handler could execute).

Comment: @MinkoGechev it should be displayed at this link https://www.mariyano.com/app-server/test/?action=get_list

Comment: @HackedByChinese can u explain how to execute the handler first then the form to submit

Comment: Is all of this wrapped in a ready callback?  What is happening instead of the expected result?

Comment: @MattWhipple there is no response!! yes it is wrapped in ready callback

Comment: @KKSuhail by no response you mean that the request is being made but you're not getting anything back? (visible in the Network tab or Console if async requests are logged).  Using an absolute path is more likely to cause issues with SOP restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no idea what's wrong but here is a working source code: http://jsfiddle.net/HLmsr/

**JavaScript**

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var name = $('#name').val() ;
  var url =  "https://www.mariyano.com/app-server/test/?action=add_list&name="+name;

  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      error: function (e) {
          console.log(e);
      },
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
});
​
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="" id="name" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />​
```

Comment: Could it be that in this example the "submit" input element is of type "button" and in your code it is "submit"? I am just guessing.

Comment: I don't think that the use of button instead input type="button" can lead to any difference if we're attaching to the click event.

Comment: There is a difference between input type="button" and input type="submit"

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var name = $('#name').val() ;
  ...
```

If you don't call preventDefault and "submit" is a submit-input type, it could happen that the code is not executed because instead the browser navigates to another page.

See jquery reference for more details: [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: This is what I was getting at when I asked the same in the comments. If this is true, you could simply `return false` at the end of the `.click` handler function. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/vxdGA/1/